# gethostbyname() sometimes could not dns forever

Tags: linux, dns, embedded-linux, glibc

In one of our product(embeded platform using RTL8196e chips), sometimes the program fails to DNS forever before the program is restarted.

More investigation found that if the program starts before the network is ready(e.g.: before DHCPed by udhcpc), the following up calling for gethostbyname() would failed for ever, even at the time ping is working when network is OK.

some tests have done to illustrate:(in the simplest form, e.g.: omit print the result of gethostbyname)

The programs are started before the network is ready(e.g.: before eth0 has get the IP by DHCP)

Program 1: could not get IP for ever after network is OK(ping is ok)

```
while (1) {
  res_init();
  gethostbyname(...); //not work
  sleep(5);
}
```

Program 2: the execution of gethostbyname() in the forked process works

```
while (1) {
  pid = fork();
  ...
  if (pid == 0)
     res_init();
     gethostbyname(...); //works
  else
     waitpid(pid1,...);
  sleep(5);
}
```

Program 3: the execution of gethostbyname() both failed in child/parent process

```
while (1) {
  pid = fork();
  ...
  if (pid == 0)
     res_init();
     gethostbyname(...); //not work
  else
     res_init();
     gethostbyname(...); //not work
     waitpid(pid1,...);
  sleep(5);
}
```

I am totally blank what's the reason for this weird behavior... Is it something about glic or kernel?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Finally I had dive to the ulibc code and find the issue.

There is bug in libc/inet/resolv.c __dns_lookup().

The variable local_ns would not get increase at some case to select the next dns server.

So the process which calls gethostbyname() would always use a false DNS server IP forever.

Due to the resolv.conf is as follows:
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 0.0.0.0
nameserver 8.8.8.8

It get deadlock to always 0.0.0.0 to query DNS...